# How to get rid of tombstones in Cassandra 1.2.13?

Tags: cassandra

I have an application which creates tombstones in my Apache Cassandra 1.2.13. I was able to get the tombstone count using cqlsh and executing a query with trace enabled which is mentioned at [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets).

How can I remove these tombstones from the keyspace ? Is there a way to do this using nodetool, cqlsh or any other tool ?

I have set the GC grace seconds to 10 seconds and ran compaction using nodetool after 10 seconds, but the tombstone count did not reduce.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Which compaction strategy is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. All I had to do was flush and then run compaction using nodetool.

All I was missing a little literature.